# select option to change image opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, opacity, onchange

I need a little help with a select option. I have a select dropdown list and when selected or onchange I need the image opacity to go from 0.3 to 1, but CAN'T USE THE VALUE of the option as it's pre-defined. Can someone help with this please?

here's the (broken) script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('input_25_custom_1011_0').onchange = img }

function img(){
if (document.getElementById('input_25_custom_1011_0').selected == true ){
document.getElementById('id_46').style.opacity = "1"; }
else { 
document.getElementById('id_46').style.opacity = "0.3"; }
}
</script>
```

and the relevant html:

```
<img alt="" class="form-image" border="0" src="http://www.jotform.com/uploads/TeckStyle/form_files/frame.png" height="334" width="225" />

      <select class="form-dropdown validate[required]" name="q25_input25[special_1011][item_0]" id="input_25_custom_1011_0">
        <option value="Standard"> Standard </option>
        <option value="Standard &amp; Rider 1"> Standard &amp; Rider 1 </option>
        <option value="Standard &amp; Rider 2"> Standard &amp; Rider 2 </option>
        <option value="Standard, Rider 1 &amp; 2"> Standard, Rider 1 &amp; 2 </option>
      </select>
```

EDIT:
updated and corrected input element.

I think the part:
if (document.getElementById('input_25_custom_1011_0').selected == true ){

needs to define which option is selected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add img id [id="id_46"]

Update your window onload function with the id of select tag

[window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('input_25_custom_1011').onchange = img }]

```
  <img alt="" id="id_46" class="form-image" border="0" src="http://www.jotform.com/uploads/TeckStyle/form_files/frame.png" height="334" width="225" />

        <select class="form-dropdown validate[required]" name="q25_input25[special_1011][item_0]" id="input_25_custom_1011_0">
          <option value="Standard"> Standard </option>
          <option value="Standard &amp; Rider 1"> Standard &amp; Rider 1 </option>
          <option value="Standard &amp; Rider 2"> Standard &amp; Rider 2 </option>
          <option value="Standard, Rider 1 &amp; 2"> Standard, Rider 1 &amp; 2 </option>
        </select>
</body>

  <script type="text/javascript">    

    window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('input_25_custom_1011_0').onchange = img }

function img(){
if (document.getElementById('input_25_custom_1011_0').selected == true ){
document.getElementById('id_46').style.opacity = "1"; }
else { 
document.getElementById('id_46').style.opacity = "0.3"; }
}


</script>
```

if you're using jQuery you can use following script as well

```
$("#input_25_custom_1011_0").on("change",function(){      

   $("img" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.3, function() {
      // Add your animation logic here.         
     // Animation done.
  });      
});
```

Comment: its the

if (document.getElementById('input_25_custom_1011_0').selected == true )

I think need to define which option is selected?

Comment: I placed the code on this jsbin: [Change Image Opacity Based On User Selection](http://jsbin.com/haxewe/3/edit)

Comment: thanks Raushan, that is the idea but shouldn't include other options for now because option 2, 3 & 4 will show other images too... is there a reason that the code from bin is not working in fiddle?

Comment: added js to head... although its not exactly whats needed, it is certainly going to help me edit/duplicate for other fields... thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your ID on which you get the img() function is incorrect. On window.load, there is no element with ID `input_25_custom_1011`.

Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tqdjshae/

I replaced the ID on the select tag with `input_25_custom_1011` and it works.

Comment: ah yes good spot, when others are chosen and option 1 is selected again it doesn't change opacity to "1"... but option 1 should make img1 opacity "1", option 2, 3 and 4 will have their own opacity functions... any ideas?